# changing the time zone in my setting does not reflect in my node js code until I terminate the server and started again

Tags: javascript, date, time

greetings I have a simple assignment in one of my classes. Which is:

Write JS code to create the following web application:

- Create an HTML table showing the 'course title', 'meeting time', 'meeting location', and 'course description' for the class ITE404.
- The title of the page must be your full name followed by your AUIS email address.
- If the client requested the page between 07:00 and 19:00, the theme of the page must be bright. Otherwise, it should be dark.

I did what my instructor was asking for. but I have one problem when I change the time zone to test whether or not the code works the code still uses the old time zone time, not the new one.

for example, when I change my time zone from Bagdad to a time zone in the US in the setting of my computer. The code still uses the Bagdad time, not the new Us time.
this is my JavaScript code:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
let fileContent;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const date = new Date();
  console.log(new Date().getMinutes());
  const time = date.getHours();
  if (time >= 7 && time < 19) fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./white.html");
  else fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./dark.html");
  res.write(fileContent);
  res.end();
});

server.listen(80);
```

this is my dark page HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>mohammed sarhad ahmed ms21126@auis.edu.krd</title>
    <style>
      body {
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
      }

      table,
      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>course title</th>
        <th>meeting time</th>
        <th>meeting location</th>
        <th>course description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITE404 – Web Application Programming</td>
        <td>Mondays and Wednesdays: from 09:45 to 11:15</td>
        <td>B-F1-16</td>
        <td>
          This course introduces students to Web server programming and
          scripting. It concentrates on familiarizing students with a
          server-side programming language such as PHP. Students will learn
          valuable skills necessary for developing HTTP-based applications. This
          course builds on ITE304, Fundamentals of Web Systems, to introduce the
          students to deeper understandings of dynamic Web systems. The course
          starts by introducing server-side programming fundamentals such as
          cookies, sessions and HTTP methods handling. Through examples,
          students will engage in building database-driven applications.
          Advanced topics such as RESTful web services, rich client integration,
          and web performance optimization are also well covered in this course.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

this my bright html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>mohammed sarhad ahmed ms21126@auis.edu.krd</title>
    <style>
      body {
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
      }
      table,
      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>course title</th>
        <th>meeting time</th>
        <th>meeting location</th>
        <th>course description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITE404 – Web Application Programming</td>
        <td>Mondays and Wednesdays: from 09:45 to 11:15</td>
        <td>B-F1-16</td>
        <td>
          This course introduces students to Web server programming and
          scripting. It concentrates on familiarizing students with a
          server-side programming language such as PHP. Students will learn
          valuable skills necessary for developing HTTP-based applications. This
          course builds on ITE304, Fundamentals of Web Systems, to introduce the
          students to deeper understandings of dynamic Web systems. The course
          starts by introducing server-side programming fundamentals such as
          cookies, sessions and HTTP methods handling. Through examples,
          students will engage in building database-driven applications.
          Advanced topics such as RESTful web services, rich client integration,
          and web performance optimization are also well covered in this course.
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should do this in the client code, not the server, so it uses the user's timezone.

Comment: And rather than having two different files, just have two classes you can apply to the body that changes the appearance from light to dark based on time of day.

Comment: how can i get the time from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Use `process.env.tz` to control your timezone in Node.JS.
You don't have to rely on your computer's timezone.